# Django model query set to list then use that list for an exclusion query on another model

Tags: python, django, get

```
    questions = Question.objects.filter(category=category)
    seen_questions_query = SeenQuestions.objects.filter(worker=user_id).only('question_id')
    seen_questions_list = list(seen_questions_query)
    questions_list = list(questions.exclude(id__in=seen_questions_list).values())
    random_sample = random.sample(questions_list, question_count)
```

I have this code above that does not work. I'm more curious about good Django practices than getting this to work.

The goal is to take a "user_id" and query for questions they've seen in the "SeenQuestions" model then turn that into a list, which will be used to query the "Question" model for all questions that don't have a primary key on the list. Then I convert that to a list and randomly sample "question_count" amount of questions, which get turned into a JSON and returned to whomever is making the GET request.

I've taken the approach above, but I don't feel like this is best Django practices, it seems like there is a better way rather than converting query sets to list then querying on that list then converting to a list again.

The above does not work because it complains about converting "seen_questions_query" to list on line 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using one single queryset.
I think you are missing `related_name` usage ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)), assuming you have not set anything, you should access related `SeeQuestions` through `question_instance.seenquestions_set`.

Below code should do the trick:

```py
seen_questions = SeenQuestion.objects.filter(worker=user_id)
questions = Question.objects.filter(category=category).exclude(seenquestions_set__in=seen_questions)
```

Finally, to dump you data as JSON you can use:

```py
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.core.serializers import serialize
serialize('json', questions, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn "questions" into a list of Question objects? So that I can return it as a JSON?

Comment: Just edited my answer. Please not that if you heavily works with JSON, I strongly suggest you use `DRF``

Comment: Thanks so much. Sorry for the added question, but I also need to take all question objects I randomly sampled and add then to SeenQuestion. Is there a way to do that with the method you suggested? Also I should mention that I have to randomly sample X questions from the table, not just return them all.